# What are the best option for a pager when building on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am building an education app and I want a pager that uses the buttons "previous" and "next" to go back and forth on the lessons I created.

Many Google results show me to use the kaminari gem but kaminiari seems to be more on the pagination(like pages 1, 2, 3...) side rather than the pager that I am looking for.

What gem or tool would be the best in my situation?

Comment: You can customize the views based on your requirements, Kaminiri has the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy kaminari's views into your app/views and edit _paginator partial.
For example, change this:

```
== paginator.render do
  nav.pagination
    = first_page_tag unless current_page.first?
    - each_page do |page|
      - if page.left_outer? || page.right_outer? || page.inside_window?
        == page_tag page
      - elsif !page.was_truncated?
        == gap_tag
    = last_page_tag unless current_page.last?
```

to that:

```
== paginator.render do
  nav.pagination
    = prev_page_tag unless current_page.first?
    = next_page_tag unless current_page.last?
```

Comment: You are right with your answer.